# Set POST file upload size for PHP server is different for near identical configuration

Tags: php

I have a local and remote server.  Both are almost the same (Centos 6x, Apache 2.2.15), but the local server has PHP Version 5.5.24 and the remote server has PHP Version 5.5.18.

On the local server, I could upload a fairly big file using blueimp's fileupload plugin, but on the remote server I received the following error:

```
POST Content-Length of 8672780 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes
```

php.ini for both of them include the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 8M
```

`phpinfo()` on both show:

```
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

Why is the local server able to upload files over 2M?  How do I make them respond identically?

Comment: Most likely `post_max_size`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size?rq=1

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Please see updated post.  Again, they seem identical, but something is different.

Comment: @j08691  Thanks for the link.  I see how both need to be set, but they appear to be the same.  Maybe I am on some edge condition where one version of PHP reads a byte or two extra?

Comment: Not sure why the difference but 8672780 bytes > 8M

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Then why would the local server allow it to be uploaded?